# How to install Python 2 on macOS 12.3+

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, homebrew, macos-monterey

macOS 12.3 update drops Python 2 and replaces it with version 3:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes

> Python
> Deprecations
> Python 2.7 was removed from macOS in this update. Developers should use Python 3 or an alternative language instead. (39795874)

I understand we need to migrate to version 3, but in the meantime we still need version 2. Homebrew does not seem to have it anymore:

```
brew install python@2.7
Warning: No available formula with the name "python@2.7". Did you mean python@3.7, python@3.9, python@3.8, python@3.10 or python-yq?

brew install python2
Warning: No available formula with the name "python2". Did you mean ipython, bpython, jython or cython?
```

What gives?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can get any Python release, including the last Python 2, from the official download site:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/ → [macOS 64-bit installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18-macosx10.9.pkg)

Comment: Thanks, thought there might be a "better" way, but this works for me. FYI this installs it into `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: its not working anymore. shows error.

Comment: @NeerPatel What shows an error?

Comment: Also, how does this solve it for non-intel Macs? ;)

Answer (score 13):

A bit more relevant information. It was removed due to the fact that [macOS remove the support of python2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-12_3-release-notes#Python), and there is [an open issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/93940) to remove all the python2 formulae as well.

Instead of using python official installer, I would suggest using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), which is easier to manage multiple python versions in your local.

Comment: I tried pyenv. It builds from source, which isn't convenient, and in my case it failed for whatever reason. `dlopen(build/lib.macosx-12.6-arm64-2.7/gdbm.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (_gdbm_close)`. Ended up just downloading from python.org in the end. I'm probably not install multiple Py2 versions, but if I do, it's easy enough to switch on-demand using `ln -sf /usr/bin/python2x /usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 12):

If, like me, you need it for development you should use PyEnv:

Here's a great tutorial:
https://dev.to/jordicuevas/how-to-install-python2-in-a-macbook-m1-with-brew-bhi

**TL;DR:**

`npm install`

`brew install pyenv`

`pyenv install 2.7.18`

`export PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:${PATH}"`

`echo 'PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH' >> ~/.zshrc`

`pyenv init`

(Follow instructions provided. I had to add to `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zshrc`.)

Make sure you load the changes by running `source ~/.zprofile` and `source ~/.zshrc`.

`pyenv shell 2.7.18`

Now, the `python` command should target Python 2 in the shell/Terminal.